# Prevent position sticky div from jumping in mobile Safari on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios

My website's hero has an effect where the div is positioned sticky within an absolutely positioned parent (whose height is determined with viewport units), such that it's bottom segment overlaps with the top segment of another component further down the page on scroll. Here's a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/hero-last-trouble-s99lb?file=/src/App.js).

All is well, until you view the page on Safari on mobile (which you can do by opening the above-linked Codesandbox and then opening the demo in a dedicated window with the button in the upper left).

This is obviously happening because of viewport changing on scroll in mobile Safari - the top bar and bottom bar shrinking whenever you scroll down.

I've looked into this, and it seems like several years ago now, Safari for iOS updated their  spec to prevent this type of jumping, by defining a fixed value for `vh` at screen load. I am perplexed while I'm still dealing with this issue, and would greatly appreciate any help in preventing it.